# PHP UTF-8 Not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, utf-8

I've got a big issue!

I've a site made in PHP with MySQL, I'm getting my data out of my Database where the characters are good!
But out of nowhere every character like á and ë e.g. are outputted as a � character.

I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks in advance,

Remy

Comment: Did you inserted the data directly into the database or via a php script?

Comment: Connect to your database using the `UTF-8` parameter, `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")`

Comment: I inserted it directly in the database

Comment: I presume that you are outputting to a web page. Is the web page UTF-8 encoded and does the font you are using support those characters?

Comment: When you directly insert data into the database it will have problems to read it. Inserting data with a php script will automatically fix this issue by encoding the characters. The set_character will also solve the problem.

Comment: There are two scenarios for getting "black diamonds".  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed your problem, and came to the conclusion that I think you forgot to add this tag:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

You should add it before you gather any data from MySQL

Comment: Thanks! It worked good!